# Weather Plugin Recommendation

Tags: plugin-recommendation

Has anyone used any of the Wordpress Weather Plugins? Any recommendations? Anyone tried out more than one? Hoping to get pointed in the right direction before I dive in.

Comment: if you looking to create one , try this tutorial to create weather reports [Kvcodes](http://www.kvcodes.com/2015/12/wordpress-how-to-get-weather-update-without-using-plugins/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you actually need plugin to do?

Interconnect IT folks had recently released pretty cool [Weather Widget](http://interconnectit.com/1474/wordpress-weather-widget/).

Comment: That plugin doesn't work anymore, the APIs we relied upon died

Answer (score 1):

I used [WP-Forecast](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-forecast/) on site a few months back. It had accurate weather data for outside of the US (I'm in Australia), a generous amount of settings and customisations and the front-end was easy to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

cool weather http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cool-weather/ is a neat one.
there is also one from weather.com called `wp-weather`
they have `widgets` and `short codes`.